# Launch another App within an App for android

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Say, I open an app and I would like to open another App after clicking a button. How can I accomplish this task? Would appreciate if you can provide me some tutorial on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();    
intent.setClassName("**package.name**", "**package.name.LauncherActivityName**");
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

You need to know the package and class names of the activity to call

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

The app you want to launch must be on the device.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent appIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("your app package name ");
startActivity(appIntent );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is a pre-packaged application mean, [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_28.html) tutorial may help you.

If the other application is going to be your application, then you need to learn Implicit Intent [tutorials](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_26.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also include the activity of the other application which you are planning to call in the Manifest file of the calling package also.