# Starting Android app that does not have icon?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application that runs another app and I use this code:

```
public void launchGoogleChrome(View view) {
        Intent launchGoogleChrome = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");
        startActivity(launchGoogleChrome);
    }
```

but if the application does not have any icon, how to start it?

Comment: What do you mean by "application don`t have any icon" ?

Comment: Why you say dont have icon? are you sure?

Comment: its hidden i need to run it from another apk

Comment: activity is null

Comment: without activity

Comment: (Removed irrelevant tags and improved grammar, but did not attempt to rephrase, as question is unfortunately unclear I might destroy information). As far as I know, if the app is not running yet, starting an activity by passing an intent should start the app. Maybe the problem is *how* you create & pass it, or somewhere else completely.

Comment: have you tried other methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073745/940834  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852087/launch-another-app-within-an-app-for-android

Answer (score 0):

If you are lost in Home screen and can't figure out the launcher icon, you can always use `adb` commands to start the application:-

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.android.chrome OR <your package name>
```

Comment: i need to run it from another apk

Comment: Then what is the problem with your code? `startActivity(Intent)`

Comment: so what to do ?

Comment: its installed but its activity is null

Comment: without activity